# Return a sub-subarray without checking for nil

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I use various versions of the code below to find a particular entry in an array of hashes and then return a different hash value or sub-array.  This multi-level array/hash structures are common when importing XML using `XMLSimple` (e.g. I don't get to control how the data structure is organized).

This will result in an error anytime find fails to locate a result:

```
value = ary.find {|r| r["rail"][0] == lookup_rail}["id"][0]
```

This will work using `tap` but gets uglier with more and more subarrays and subhashes.

```
ary.find {|r| r["rail"][0] == lookup_rail}.tap do |f|
  value = f.nil? ? nil : (f["id"].nil? nil : f["id"][0])
end
```

Is there a way to not have the program error out if I reference a sub-array of a nil object (without adding to `NilClass`)?

Is there a way to check for the existence of the sub-sub-array entry and then perform any assignment operations?

Comment: Do you have any sample data we could play with to find the best solution?

Comment: The question could be improved, but I found it very interesting, particularly the challenge of a more general solution.

Comment: Thanks Cary.  I kept hitting this same issue and figured that there had to be a standard method for handling these cases.  I had a hard time writing the question so it was not subjective :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 2.0+, `nil.to_h` is `{ }`; also, `nil.to_a` has been `[ ]` as long as I can remember. Of course, if `h` is a Hash then `h.to_h` is `h` and if `a` is an Array then `a.to_a` is `a`. You can use this to hide `nil`s thusly:

```
value = ary.find {|r| r["rail"][0] == lookup_rail}.to_h["id"].to_a[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `&&`?

```
x = {"id" => ["train"]}
x && x["id"] && x["id"][0]
# => "train"

x = {"id" => nil}
x && x["id"] && x["id"][0]
# => nil

x = nil
x && x["id"] && x["id"][0]
# => nil
```

---

```
ary.find {|r| r["rail"][0] == lookup_rail}.tap do |f|
  value = f && f["id"] && f["id"][0]
end
```